# Selecting nested element

Tags: css

I have a class assigned to the first div within a div with class "level". Works fine.

I need to swap the style if the parent div has an id="selected". Having difficulty selecting it...

```
.level:first-child div:nth-child(1) {
    background-position: 0px -368px;
}
.level:first-child div:nth-child(1) #selected {
    background-position: 0px -429px;
    background-color:red
}
```

```
<div class="level" id="selected">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `id` in front

```
#selected.level:first-child div:nth-child(1)  {
    background-position: 0px -429px;
    background-color:red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.level:first-child div:nth-child(1) {
    background-position: 0px -368px;
}
.level:first-child#selected div:nth-child(1) {
    background-position: 0px -429px;
    background-color:red
}​
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/HARWp/1/